# Set the dependent dropdown's default value in select2 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2, wicket

In a wicket application, I have two dependent dropdowns using Select2. Now, I want to set the default value of both dropdowns. The default value should be the first element of the choiceList.
Second dropdown's default value should be updated accordingly if I select other option from the choice in the first dropdown.

1. I have used Placeholder but didn't succeed. How can I update the placeholder value dynamically?
2. I tried the below code but the second dropdown's default value is not updating automatically.

```
private static class ValueEditor extends Select2Choice<String> {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = SingleFiniteValueEditor.serialVersionUID;

        ValueEditor(String id, EditableSingleFiniteModel<?> model, ChoiceProvider<String> provider) {
            super(id, model.valueModel(), provider);
            setOutputMarkupId(true);
            getSettings().setDropdownAutoWidth(true);
            getSettings().setCloseOnSelect(true);
            getSettings().setPlaceholder("");
            getSettings().setAllowClear(!model.mandatory());
            if(!model.choices().getObject().isEmpty()) {
                model.valueModel().setObject(model.choices().getObject().get(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onInitialize() {
            super.onInitialize();
            add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = SingleFiniteValueEditor.serialVersionUID;

                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    target.add(getComponent().getParent());
                    target.prependJavaScript(JQuery.execute("$('#%s').select2('destroy');", getJquerySafeMarkupId()));
                    target.appendJavaScript(JQuery.execute("$('#%s').select2('focus');", getJquerySafeMarkupId()));
                    send(getComponent(), Broadcast.BUBBLE, new ValueChangedEvent());
                }
            });
            // FIXME append a class and style in stylesheet?
            add(AttributeModifier.append("style", "min-width:200px;"));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag) {
            tag.setName("select");
            super.onComponentTag(tag);
        }
    }
```

I am new to the wicket framework so please help me with this problem.

First, two dropdowns are dependent dropdowns as shown in the fig [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydP8Z.png). Second dropdown's choice list is depend on first dropdown's selected value.

Comment: two dependent dropdown? could you share a image?

Comment: Please refer the above link and description.